# Spring-boot JPA taking long time retrieve records from 15 tables

Tags: spring-boot

We have requirement to retrieve records passing 2000 Ids. We have 15 tables, I am using JPA repository **findById** method, when I search for 1 record its taking 6 seconds to retrieve records from 15 tables (We have entity classes which are mapped\joincolumns on IDs).

Please suggest how we can optimize this from JPA side.

Also appreciate for any idea how I can use **ComputableFuture** interface to have multiple threads retrieving records with 200 IDs splitted between threads.

Comment: So you have a join of 15 tables ??

Comment: Yes, I can see master table calls once with IN operator and then all 14 select query invoked then for each correlationID

Comment: Yes you are correct. when you have one to many or one one mapping hibernate execute another separate query to fetch it from the database. We had the same issue, we overcame that by manually fetching child records using IN query.

Comment: log the generated SQL query and check if you can support the query with a further index on the database.

Comment: I am using Redshift db, there is no index support, I have to create primary keys\not null types